# Compare text file and table values for insert/update/delete

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I have text file which looks like as below,

```
ID1~name1~city1~zipcode1~position1
ID2~name2~city2~zipcode2~position2
ID3~name3~city3~zipcode3~position3
ID4~name4~city4~zipcode4~position4
.
.
etc goes on...
```

This text file is the source file and I want split the file (`~`) and compare the table with ID.
If the value is not in the table, insert operation should perform. 
If the id is available in the table but other column values are different then need to update the table. 
If the id is not available in the text but available in the table then then the record should get deleted.

I did goggle it but i could find the below page,

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27419804/VBScript-compare-differences-in-two-record-sets.html

Please help me how I can proceed with VBscript.

Answer (score 1):

Whose leg you are trying to pull? Obviously the desired/resulting table is the input table, so use ["load data infile"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import the file.

Comment: Thanks but this is oracle database. How is this syntax works?

Comment: So that's why you tagged your question "mysql"?